# How can I manipulate the content of a file, by duplicating and changing some parts?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I want to manipulate a text-file. It contains many blocks of the form

```
CLASS
   ...some stuff ...
END
```

I want to duplicate each of these blocks and add and remove a line of it's content. Can I script that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The natural tools for this are awk and Perl (assuming you want to script: for a once-off, the natural tool is an interactive editor). Here's an awk script that duplicates all `CLASS`…`END` blocks (no balancing supported: each `CLASS` matches the next `END`), except that `foo` lines are omitted from the second copy.

```
awk '
  /^CLASS$/ { store = 1; }  # start storing
  store && ! /^foo$/ { hold = hold ORS $0; }  # if storing, maybe save line
  /^END$/ {
      $0 = $0 hold;  # append hold copy to current line
      store = 0; hold = "";  # end of block
  }
  1 { print; }  # print original line, with hold prepended if at end of block
'
```

Here's a sed solution; don't take it too seriously. Don't expect it to behave if the `CLASS`/`END` lines are not in strict alternation.

```
sed -e '/^CLASS$/,/^END$/!b' \
    -e '/^CLASS$/{' -e 'h' -e 'b' -e '}' \
    -e '/^foo$/!H' \
    -e '/^END$/G'
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, you *can* script anything.

However, if I were doing this, I would use `vim` macros.  (If you are not familiar with `vim` already, you should learn it, but otherwise ignore this)

A few basic pointers:

q  -- start recording a macro

qx -- stop recording a macro and name it 'x'

@x -- run the macro named 'x'

A macro will immediately re-run whatever commands you typed during the recording session.

So if you wanted a macro to duplicate a block like that type:

```
q          start macro
/CLASS     jump to next "CLASS"
V          start selecting full lines
/END       jump to next "END
Y          yank selected lines (yank = copy)
j          scroll down one line
p          put (paste)
qd         stop recording and name the macro d
```

There are plenty of good resources and examples out there for vim usages and vim macros.

For what it's worth, sed is a sort of a command line version of vim, so you might be able to adapt what I said to sed, but I'm less familiar with it, so I can't vouch for it.

~~ edit ~~

Another thing that makes this more useful is `vim`'s ability to open up multiple files.  Multiple files opened are referred to as buffers.  You activate this by having multiple filenames after `vim` (IE `vim *.txt` to open all txt files)

To run a macro on multiple buffers, first open up all the files at the same time.  Then, use `:bufdo normal @x` to run the macro `x` on each buffer.

Note, you must have `:w` as the last step of the macro to avoid getting stuck when it tries to switch to the next buffer if the current one isn't saved.

`:bn` will take manually to the next buffer.

Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291962/replay-a-vim-macro-until-end-of-buffer for how to run a macro for each line.  Mix and match :)

Answer (score 1):

The exact tool to use will depend on the specifics of the job.  If the job is only going to happen once, you might consider using a macro in `vim` or `emacs`.  If you truly want to script it, I would look into `sed`:

> Sed  is a stream editor.  A stream editor is used to perform basic text
>          transformations on an input stream (a file or input from  a  pipeline).

Again, the exact way to do this is will depend on your situation, but to add a line after a line starting with PATTERN you can do this:

```
sed -e 's/\(^PATTERN.*\)/\1\nTextToAdd/' file.old > file.new
```

To add a line before a line starting with PATTERN you could do something like this:

```
sed -e 's/\(^PATTERN.*\)/TextToAdd\n\1/' file.old > file.new
```

To remove a line starting with PATTERN

```
sed -e 's/\(^PATTERN.*\)//' file.old > file.new
```

The trick will be to find the correct PATTERN that will catch only the lines you want.

You can combine these by doing soemthing like this:

```
sed -e 's/\(^PATTERN1.*\)/\1\nTextToAdd/' -e 's/\(^PATTERN2.*\)/TextToAdd\n\1/' file.old > file.new
```

Comment: To find only blocks beetwen `CLASS` and `END` we could use `sed -n -e '/^CLASS$/,/^END$/p' file.txt`, but as sed is stream editor we are getting blocks in parts - each word is another part so we should remeber everything after `CLASS` and before `END` and then paste it to file. I think that tool better than `sed` in this case will be `awk`, but as I don't know it I spent one and half hour trying to write some useful awk script and I failed... ;)

Comment: Completely right, I didn't read this question closely enough before firing off an answer.

Answer (score 1):

And Python solution from me:

```
file = open('a.txt', 'r')
arr = []
tmp = []
remember = False

for line in file:
    if "CLASS" in line:
        remember = True     # start storing lines
        tmp.append(line)    # we're storing lines in list
        continue            # go to next line
    if "END" in line:
        tmp.append(line)    # store line
        remember = False    # stop storing lines
        arr.append(tmp)     # add line to list
        tmp = []            # clear temp list
        continue            # go to next line
    if remember:
        tmp.append(line)    # add to list line between CLASS and END
file.close()

file = open('a.txt', 'a')
for tmp in arr:
    if '   ...some stuff ...1\n' in tmp:    # we can skip 
        continue                            # whole block if we find this
    for i in tmp:
        if "333" in i:  # we can skip only one line 
            continue
        file.write(i)
file.close()
```

I think that it is easiest to understand and modify than awk version (if you don't know awk)... Btw awk is next language on my list of languages that I want to learn... ;)